# Is GCM limit of 100-message/4-collapse-key per device or per Registration ID

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

There are two GCM limits according to GCM documentation. One is that the GCM server can hold up to 100 messages while device is offline.
The other one is that there can only be up to 4 collapse keys `PER SENDER_ID PER DEVICE`.

In our use case, we can have 5 or more different apps (each one is an APK) installed on a single device and each of them registers and obtains a GCM registration id independently (using same `SENDER_ID` though, as we only have one Google project on server side), does each app have its own 100/4 quota or all 5 apps share the same 100/4 quota?

If all 5 apps share the same 100/4 quota, then it is very likely that after then phone gets back on line (from sleep), one or some apps will not be able to receive any queued GCM message, in the case when there are more than 100 messages queued on GCM server (hence all deleted, leaving a single special "you-need-to-perform-full-sync" message, to which app out of 5?) or the 4-collapse-key limit kills the 5th collapse-able message.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the 100/4 quota is per Registration ID (which means separate quota for each app, regardless of whether or not you are using the same sender ID for the different apps).

The documentation doesn't say that the 100/4 quota is per sender ID. It says it is per device. However, since it doesn't make sense that all the apps on a single device will share the same quota, I assume that the quota is per application per device (i.e. per Registration ID).

Answer (score 0):

From the Android Developer Documentation,

> GCM only allows a maximum of 4 different collapse keys to be used by the GCM server per >device at any given time.

You can specify as many collapse keys as you want. But if a message is not push to the device yet, the maximum unique collapse key stored by GCM will be 4.

Answer (score 0):

The limit on GCM  4 collapse_keys and per 100 messages is per Registration ID so 
the other apps will not affected.